# Using SSIS Environment Variables With VB Program

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, ssis

Good Afternoon,

I have created an SSIS Project with a single package in it.  The SSIS Project and Package work as I expect when I manually executed from the server. I thought that if I set an environment variable on the server and mapped it to the project. That the project would then use those variables every time the package was executed unless otherwise told.  The following code is my VB code

```
'VB.Net code
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices
Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub StartPackageButton_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles StartPackageButton.Click
        Try
        ' Connection to the database server where the packages are located
        Dim ssisConnection As New SqlConnection("Data Source=" + txtServerName.Text + ";Integrated Security=SSPI;")

        ' SSIS server object with connection
        Dim ssisServer As New IntegrationServices(ssisConnection)


        ' The reference to the package which you want to execute
        Dim ssisPackage As PackageInfo = ssisServer.Catalogs("SSISDB").Folders("SSIS_PROJECTS").Projects("AgressoExport").Packages("File56Export.dtsx")

        ' Add a parameter collection for 'system' parameters (ObjectType = 50), package parameters (ObjectType = 30) and project parameters (ObjectType = 20)
        Dim executionParameters As New Collection(Of PackageInfo.ExecutionValueParameterSet)

        ' Add execution parameter to override the default asynchronized execution. If you leave this out the package is executed asynchronized
        Dim executionParameter1 As New PackageInfo.ExecutionValueParameterSet
        executionParameter1.ObjectType = 50
        executionParameter1.ParameterName = "SYNCHRONIZED"
        executionParameter1.ParameterValue = 1
        executionParameters.Add(executionParameter1)

        ' Add execution parameter (value) to override the default logging level (0=None, 1=Basic, 2=Performance, 3=Verbose)
        Dim executionParameter2 As New PackageInfo.ExecutionValueParameterSet
        executionParameter2.ObjectType = 50
        executionParameter2.ParameterName = "LOGGING_LEVEL"
        executionParameter2.ParameterValue = 3
        executionParameters.Add(executionParameter2)

        ' Add execution parameter (value) to override the default logging level (0=None, 1=Basic, 2=Performance, 3=Verbose)
        Dim executionParameter3 As New PackageInfo.ExecutionValueParameterSet
        If (Trim(txtPreviousID.Text) <> "") Then
            executionParameter3.ObjectType = 20
            executionParameter3.ParameterName = "PreviousBatchID"
            executionParameter3.ParameterValue = txtPreviousID.Text
            executionParameters.Add(executionParameter3)
        End If

        ' Get the identifier of the execution to get the log
        Dim executionIdentifier As Long = ssisPackage.Execute(False, Nothing, executionParameters)

        ' Loop through the log and add the messages to the listbox
        For Each message As OperationMessage In ssisServer.Catalogs("SSISDB").Executions(executionIdentifier).Messages
            SSISMessagesListBox.Items.Add(message.MessageType.ToString() + ": " + message.Message)
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        If ex.InnerException IsNot Nothing Then
            SSISMessagesListBox.Items.Add(ex.Message.ToString() + " : " + ex.InnerException.Message.ToString())
        Else
            SSISMessagesListBox.Items.Add(ex.Message.ToString())
        End If
    End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

I'm starting to think that I did not understand environments correctly when it comes to SSIS.  My environment was setup as TEST and PROD on their respective servers with the same variable names mapped to the same parameters but with different values.  I am starting to believe I should have had the same Environment name on both the TEST and PROD server, which I would then refer too using my VB code.  I have not been able to find out how to refer to the Environment using VB yet either though.

I would appreciate any help on the matter.

Cheers,
Johnathan

Comment: I believe I have gotten slightly closer to the resolution, I have found that I needed to get the Environment Reference Handle I did this using

`Dim re As EnvironmentReference`
`re = ssisServer.Catalogs("SSISDB").Folders("SSIS_PROJECTS").Projects("AgressoExport").References("AgressoExport", "MASTER")`

then I changed the Execute command to the following

`Dim executionIdentifier As Long = ssisPackage.Execute(False, re, executionParamters))`

Unfortunately I am still getting the same error stating that I must define all parameters.

Comment: Found out the issue with the second update was I should have used `References("AgressoExport", ".")` to indicate that I wanted the AgressoExport Environment in the root folder.

Answer (score 0):

For the purpose ssis have given facility of configuration and you have to just  create separate cofig file or db entry  for your different environment .

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141682.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `reference` property of the package to be the ID of the environment.

To get the environment ID try:

```
DECLARE @environment_id AS BIGINT
SELECT @environment_id = reference_id FROM SSISDB.internal.environment_references where environment_name = 'your environment name'
```

Answer (score 0):

To be able to use Environments inside a Visual Basic .NET program.  You need to declare the Environment Reference and pass the reference to the Execute Method of the SSIS Package.

The following block of code is how it is done:

```
Dim re As EnvironmentReference
re = ssisServer.Catalogs("SSISDB").Folders("SSIS_PROJECTS").Projects("AgressoExport").References("AgressoExport", ".")

Dim executionIdentifier As Long = ssisPackage.Execute(False, re, executionParameters)
```

SSISDB is the catalog name, SSIS_PROJECTS is the folder name under the catalog that I am using.  AgressoExport is my Project Name.  ("AgressoExport", ".") refers to the Environment named AgressoExport under my project in the root of the Environment Folder.

Cheers